# How to bind innerHTML with translate

Tags: angular, pipe

Hi I have a problem with binding into property to get html and translate it from json: [innerHTML]="articles.{{articleId}}.description | translate".

```
"articles": [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "title": "Title phone", 
        "description": "<p>some text</p>",
        "img": "article-1.png",
        "alt": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "title": "this is title", 
        "description": "<p>Some text</p>
        "img": "article-2.jpg",
        "alt": "MacBook"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share us what you have tried so far. your component.ts and component.html

Answer (score 0):

To diplay all the articles you can use the following cpde

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles">
  <div [innerHTML]="article.description | translate"></div>
</div>
```

Or to display specific article use the following code

```
<div [innerHTML]="articles[articleId].description | translate"></div>
```

Comment: I want to do something like this: <div [innerHTML]="articles{{articleId}}.description | translate"></div> dynamically change articleId not pass exacly number to array.

Comment: You can change [0] with your articleId.
<div [innerHTML]="articles[articleId].description | translate"></div>
(just updated answer)

Comment: This give me error Cannot read property '1' of undefined for description, title shows good result: <h2 translate>articles.{{articleId}}.title</h2> <div [innerHTML]="articles[articleId].description | translate"></div>

Comment: I did something like this but still i cant put dynamic article id into [innerHTML]="translate.instant('articles.1.description')"

Comment: You can check pierreduc's answer, he has explained the answer very well.
First you need to grab the article in typescript file and then bind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a component function which gets the right article from you. The problem is that this function will be called with ever `DoCheck` which might not be very performant. Another option would be to create a reusable pipe which you can convert the article items to a id -> article object:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'keyObjects'
})
export class KeyObjectsPipe<T = any> implements PipeTransform {

  transform(objects: T[], key: keyof T): {[key: string]: T}[] {
    return (objects || []).map((object) => ({[object[key]]: object }));
  } 
}
```

Because this is a pure pipe, it will not be called with every `DoCheck`, and you can reuse this logic for any other objects you might have this. The usage will be:

```
<div [innerHTML]="(articles | keyObjects:'id')[articleId]?.description | translate"></div>
```

Another, and maybe even better option, would be to create an Observable which contains the `articleId` stream. You can then map this one, together with the `articles` stream to get the right object:

```
//pseudo
articles$: Observable<Article[]> = this.http.get('/articles'); 

// if you have :article as route param
articleId$ = this.route.params.pipe(map(({ article }) => article));

// get the right article
article$ = combineLatest(
  this.articles$,
  this.articleId$
).pipe(
  map(([ articles, articleId ]) => articles.find((article) => article.id === articleId)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

You can then use this with the `async` pipe:

```
<div [innerHTML]="(article$ | async)?.description | translate"></div>
```